# Click Function to Run After Group Expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013

When SP groups are collapsed you can't run a `click` function on `doc.ready`.  I've got the following script to run when an item is expanded and it runs my `click` function (this is on a boxed list view).  The problem is it will run multiple times depending on how many times the list is expanded (if 3 groups expanded it will run the `click` function 3 times).  I'm aware it's because I have a function within a function but I'm unclear how to resolve it since I need it to run when the groups are expanded, just not one time for every expanded instance.  Here is basically what I'm using (not exact but to give you an idea....

```
function FixTheThings() {
  var oldExpand = ProcessImn;
  ProcessImn = function() {
    var results = oldExpand.apply(this, arguments);
    createImages();
    return results;
  }
}

function createImages() {
  $("td.ms-stylebox").on("click", function() {
    var yup = $(this).find(".stylebody").first().html();
    OpenPopUpPage('link?ID=' + yup, RefreshPage);
  });
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing brace on the `createImages` method.

Comment: Updated.  I didn't copy it directly but its in my actual script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working by placing `$("td.ms-stylebox").unbind("click");` before my actual `click` function